# How can I filter a queryset based upon two manytomany relationships having one object in common?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Suppose I have a queryset of animals and I want to write a query that determines if a manytomany field on another model has at least one object in common with the animals queryset. How can this be acheived?

```
farm_animals = Animals.objects.filter(name__in=["Dog", "Cow", "Horse"])

print farm_animals # [<Animal: Dog>, <Animal: Cow>, <Animal: Horse>]

# Returns all people who have at least one farm animal.
people_with_a_farm_animal = People.objects.filter(???)
```

This seems like it should be easy to do, but I'm struggling to find a good efficient way to do it. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by danihp, if a `People` object has a `owned_animals` field try `people_with_a_farm_animal = People.objects.filter( owned_animals__in=farm_animals).distinct()`.

Comment: You are close to downvote action. This is a better approach but is not a solution.

Comment: @danihp care to explain how it isn't?

Comment: Answer is: `people_with_a_farm_animal = People.objects.filter( owned_animals__in=farm_animals).distinct()`

Comment: @danihp you're right, but why threaten downvote rather than submit your own answer?

Comment: @thomallen, more funny, keep me in your mind when you have overwork in tesla: http://www.grabthar.com  ;)

Comment: @thomallen, Never give up, never surrender! Bye!