# postgres - having group by min of date time and status

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to retrieve car_id from the below table which have 
min (svc_date) with  status=A   .

expected is 103 and 100 which have status 'A'

because it have the status A with minimum svc_date

```
car_id   svc_date            status

100     03/01/2013          A           
100     04/02/2013          B
100     05/03/2013          C 
101     06/01/2013          A
101     05/01/2013          B
102     06/06/2013          A
102     05/05/2013          B 
103     05/25/2013          A
```

i am using postgres and am trying

```
    select   car_id,svc_date,status  from  car_tbl  group by 
car_id having min(svc_date) and status='A'
```

svc_date is timestamp with timezone  and 
getting error

```
  argument of AND must be type boolean, not type timestamp with time zone
```

is the entire sql is wrong or any type cast will help?

Comment: Please explain your expected results. Do you want `min` per `car_id`?

Comment: expceted is 103 and 100 which have status 'A' with minimum or least svc date

Comment: zod, expain before downvote storm.

Comment: Expected answer is: Grouping by id and sorting group by date, take only groups that 'A' is in the top of the group position.

Comment: @zod, please, read previous comment and edit your question to match requirements.

Comment: I don't like to downvote ( [sample](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16886828/842935) ) But I can understand people than downvote this question. After request for more detailed you reply one time and other the same. Please, fix question.

Comment: @danihp - Still do not understand how you guessed it. Bravo!

Comment: i think --- why he understand because he is not from English speaking country . Just like me . anyway he said "Really, it is hard to understand to you:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really, it is hard to understand to you:

```
with cte as (
select 
  car_id ,
  status,
  rank() OVER (
     PARTITION BY car_id 
     ORDER BY svc_date )       
from car_tbl
)
select * 
from cte 
where rank = 1 
and status = 'A'
```

[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/fc2a7/8/0):

```
| CAR_ID | STATUS | RANK |
--------------------------
|    100 |      A |    1 |
|    103 |      A |    1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

It's rather difficult to see what you're really asking; but does this do what you want?

```
SELECT car_id, status, MIN(svc_date) FROM car_tbl WHERE status = 'A' GROUP BY car_id, status
```

Comment: That's what I thought too, but it does not give just `100` and `103` as OP insists.

Comment: this will return all car_id  's  minimum date of  status  A. what i need is    return car_id only if its miinimum date have status A . if its min dat status B dont return that id