# Loop through fields in Django model class

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to eliminate duplicate code within my models.py file, but the following loop does not work and returns "OperationalError no such column my_app.rank."

```
from django.db import models

rank_fields = [
    'E1', 'E2','E3', 'E4', 'E5', 'E6', 'E7', 'E8', 'E9',
    'W1', 'W2', 'W3', 'W4', 'W5', 'O1E', 'O2E', 'O3E', 'O1',
    'O2', 'O3', 'O4', 'O5', 'O6', 'O7', 'O8', 'O9', 'O10'
]

class withDependents(models.Model):
    MHA = models.CharField(max_length = 5)
    for rank in rank_fields:
        rank = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2)
```

Edit:

I found one possible solution that works:

```
# add rank fields to withDependents and withOutDependents
rank_fields = [
    'E1', 'E2','E3', 'E4', 'E5', 'E6', 'E7', 'E8', 'E9',
    'W1', 'W2', 'W3', 'W4', 'W5', 'O1E', 'O2E', 'O3E', 'O1',
    'O2', 'O3', 'O4', 'O5', 'O6', 'O7', 'O8', 'O9', 'O10'
    ]

for rank in rank_fields:
        withDependents.add_to_class(rank, models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2))
        withOutDependents.add_to_class(rank, models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2))
```

Comment: If these fields don't warrant enough attention to have their own field definitions then why are they not put in a separate table altogether?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? In your first code snippet you are overriding rank every time the forloop loops.

Comment: @vishen, finally I have abled to post an answer.  I'm specializing on [unintelligible questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991724/postgres-having-group-by-min-of-date-time-and-status)  ;)

Comment: I should have been clearer. I had a long list of similar fields labeled E1, E2, etc. I was trying to clean up the code and use a for loop to assign my fields to the model class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way is to use [contribute_to_class](http://blog.jupo.org/2011/11/10/django-model-field-injection/) field method on class_prepared:

```
from django.db.models import DecimalField
from django.db.models.signals import class_prepared

def add_fields(sender, **kwargs):
    if sender.__name__ == "withDependents":
        for rank in rank_fields:
            field = DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2)
            field.contribute_to_class(sender, rank)

class_prepared.connect(add_fields)
```